# How do you use TypeScript typings that are modules?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I'm trying to use [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) to load a definition file for [bowser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bowser). I've got typings installed and run `typings install dt~bowser -DG --save-dev` to install it locally. This works great. However now I'm at a loss as to how to use it. In the past, it has "just worked" - meaning, now if I try and write something that references bowser in TypeScript, it will find my definition file (downloaded with typings from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)) and recognize `bowser` as a global function. Now however, it looks like the definition file has changed and it's now a "module":

```
declare module 'bowser' {
   var def: BowserModule.IBowser;
   export = def;
}
```

How am I supposed to use this in my TypeScript files? Of course I can do something like this:

```
declare var bowser: BowserModule.IBowser;
```

But that feels wrong/hacky. What am I missing here-- what's changed in the world of typings/DefinitelyTyped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The correct syntax would be](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require)

```
import bowser = require('bowser')
```

If your typings are properly configured, it should work. Else, check if the `typings/index.d.ts` file is referenced in your build script, and if bowser is properly referenced in there:

```
/// <reference path="globals/bowser/index.d.ts" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, that got me further. However now it's saying it can't find regular exported classes I've defined in my own other .ts files. I was able to add another `import` statement to fix it -- but this seems crazy? Once you add one `import` does it require all external dependencies to be imported from that point forward?

Comment: The `/// <reference` lines must be the first thing in the file, before any kind of code. Maybe this is the issue ?

Comment: Though if you ask me, I think ES6-standard "import" statements should be used if possible

Comment: I'm going to ask a separate question with code examples-- you answered my original one fine. Thanks for the help thus far!