# Using an import statement breaks other class references?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

As a followup to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112501/how-do-you-use-typescript-typings-that-are-modules/39118144) about using the `bowser` DefinitelyTyped definition file specifically, I implemented the `import` statement as directed by the answer in that question and got further. However now the TypeScript compiler is complaining about code that compiled perfectly fine before all the bowser import nonsense.

Let's say I have MyBowserClass.ts:

```js
import bowser = require('bowser');

namespace MyNamespace {
    export class MyBowserClass {
        constructor() {
            var isIos = (typeof bowser.ios === 'undefined') ? false : bowser.ios;
            alert(isIos);

            var myInstance = new MyNamespaceTwo.MyOtherClass(); // typescript compiler complains: Property 'MyOtherClass' does not exist on type 'typeof MyNamespaceTwo'.
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have MyOtherClass.ts:

```js
namespace MyNamespaceTwo {
    export class MyOtherClass {
        constructor() {
            alert('otherclass ctor');
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler is giving me an error here:

`var myInstance = new MyNamespaceTwo.MyOtherClass();`

saying `Property 'MyOtherClass' does not exist on type 'typeof MyNamespaceTwo'.`

So I guess maybe this means I need to also import `MyOtherClass`?

I got this to work by updating my two files:

```js
import bowser = require('bowser');
import otherClass = require('MyOtherClass'); // NEW IMPORT

namespace MyNamespace {
    export class MyBowserClass {
        constructor() {
            var isIos = (typeof bowser.ios === 'undefined') ? false : bowser.ios;
            alert(isIos);

            var myInstance = new otherClass.MyNamespaceTwo.MyOtherClass(); // changed this to prefix with 'otherClass'
        }
    }
}
```

```js
export namespace MyNamespaceTwo { // made this EXPORT
    export class MyOtherClass {
        constructor() {
            alert('otherclass ctor');
        }
    }
}
```

This seems like total chaos/craziness. What am I missing here? Why should the `bowser` definition file be a module anyway (when it consists of a global/essentially static method name??) Any guidance/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you update the question and instead of trying to describe what you changed, please post the code after the change? It will make it much easier to understand.

Comment: @NitzanTomer there you go. hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're changing your file from a global declaration file to a module declaration file.

- a **global declaration file** makes the types declared in it accessible in your entire project, without the need to import anything. Global declaration files can never import from another file. They also never export, as the types declared in it are available everywhere.

  Eg. a project that uses [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) could declare a `SpecialAction` that can then be used anywhere in the project:

  ```
  // index.d.ts
  interface SpecialAction {
    type: string
    isSpecial: boolean
  }

  // src/app.ts
  let theAction: SpecialAction = {
    type: 'SPECIAL',
    isSpecial: true
  }
  ```
- a **module declaration file** exports specific types to a module, so the exports can be imported elsewhere in your project. As soon as you import or export in a declaration file, it becomes a module declaration file.

  ```
  // index.d.ts
  import { Action } from 'redux'
  export interface SpecialAction extends Action {
    isSpecial: boolean
  }

  // src/app.ts
  import { SpecialAction } from '../index'
  let theAction: SpecialAction = {
    type: 'SPECIAL',
    isSpecial: true
  }
  ```

I hope this helps? `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I guess this helps answer my question: `As soon as you import or export in a declaration file, it becomes a module declaration file.` My `import bowser = require('bowser');` line is making my file a "module declaration". Which I wouldn't expect. I feel pretty dumb about all this, guess it's time for me to read up.

Comment: That's what SO is for right  I've lost countless hours myself before I finally got it. I'm happy I could help!

Comment: So thanks for that too Pelle, but how do I solve whereby I want to access `moment` in my export class (which was for @types support)? I suffer the same issues when adding `import moment = require('moment');` to the top of the file.